# Can a function define instance variables when called inside a function in Python?

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask app that has a lot of functions with duplicate parts. To make the code simpler, I want to call a helper function instead of repeating code, including variable definitions.

```
@app.route('/update_report', methods=["POST"])
def update_report():
    m_log_no = request.form.get('log_no')
    m_ip_address = request.form.get('ip_address')
    m_report_reason = request.form.get('report_reason')
    m_status_code = request.form.get('status_code')
    ...
@app.route('/delete_report', methods=["POST"])
def delete_report():
    m_log_no = request.form.get('log_no')
    m_user_id= request.form.get('user_id')
    ...
```

I have hundreds of functions like this. I would like to simplify it by using a helper function to define instance variables:

```
def helper_function(*args)
    for arg in args:
        # Work some magic of sorts:
        # super.m_arg = request.form.get(arg)

@app.route('/update_report', methods=["POST"])
def update_report():
    parameter_list = ('log_no', 'ip_address', 'report_reason', 'status_code')
    helper_function(*parameter_list)
```

Is this sort of action possible?

Answer (score 0):

You do something on these lines, if it suffices your need.

```
class FormData(object):

    # Using __init__ as per bruno's comment
    def __init__(self, parameters_list, data_object, *args, **kwargs):
        for form_key_item in parameters_list:
            setattr(self, "m_{key_name}".format(key_name=form_key_item), data_object.get(form_key_item))


    # Custom method
    def set_args(self, parameters_list, data_object):
        for form_key_item in parameters_list:
            setattr(self, "m_{key_name}".format(key_name=form_key_item), data_object.get(form_key_item))
```

And use it like

```
def some_method():
    # While using the custom method for setting values
    # Create your data instance
    your_data_object = FormData()
    # Set the value for the attributes on instance
    your_data_object.set_args(parameters_list, request.form)

    # While using the __init__ method
    your_data_object = FormData(parameters_list, request.form)

    # Use it like
    print(your_data_object.m_log_no)
```

P.S: This is a rough draft which you can use.

Comment: Why use a distinct `set_args` method when you could just use the `__init__()` to do the job ?

Comment: That would work for the code sample that I gave. But if it were a classmethod, then `__init__` wouldn't suffice. Also, just wanted to give the OP an idea about how he might be able to set values on object attributes using his existing helper methods.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to send the `request` to the helper function. Return a dictionary containing the parameters and form values from the helper function.

Here is a demonstration of this concept:

`app.py`:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

def helper_function(flask_request, args):
    data = {}
    for arg in args:
        data[arg] = flask_request.form.get(arg)
    return data

@app.route('/update_report', methods=["POST"])
def update_report():
    parameter_list = ('log_no', 'ip_address')
    data = helper_function(request, parameter_list)
    return jsonify(data)

@app.route('/delete_report', methods=["POST"])
def delete_report():
    parameter_list = ('log_no', 'user_id')
    data = helper_function(request, parameter_list)
    return jsonify(data)


@app.route('/', methods=["GET"])
def view_reports():
    return render_template("form.html")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

`form.html`:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Form</title>     
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>Update report</h3>
        <form action="/update_report" method="post">
            Log No: <input name="log_no" /> <br>
            IP Address: <input name="ip_address" /> <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Update" />
        </form>             
        <hr>
        <h3>Delete report</h3>
        <form action="/delete_report" method="post">
            Log No: <input name="log_no" /> <br>
            User ID: <input name="user_id" /> <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
        </form>             
    </body>
</html>
```

**Output:**

- Figure 1: Form view before calling the update or delete route
  [image: form view]
- Figure 2: Response after calling the update route
  [image: output_from_helper]